# Erro: FFMPEG não encontrado

Tags: javascript

```
const { Client, Util } = require('discord.js');
const { TOKEN, PREFIX, GOOGLE_API_KEY } = require('./config');
const YouTube = require('simple-youtube-api');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const client = new Client({ disableEveryone: true });

const youtube = new YouTube(GOOGLE_API_KEY);

const queue = new Map();

require('http').createServer().listen(3000)


client.on('warn', console.warn);

client.on('error', console.error);

client.on('ready', () => console.log('Yo this ready!'));

client.on('disconnect', () => console.log('I just disconnected, making sure you know, I will reconnect now...'));

client.on('reconnecting', () => console.log('I am reconnecting now!'));

client.on('message', async msg => { // eslint-disable-line
    if (msg.author.bot) return undefined;
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return undefined;

    const args = msg.content.split(' ');
    const searchString = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    const url = args[1] ? args[1].replace(/<(.+)>/g, '$1') : '';
    const serverQueue = queue.get(msg.guild.id);

    let command = msg.content.toLowerCase().split(' ')[0];
    command = command.slice(PREFIX.length)

    if (command === 'play') {
        const voiceChannel = msg.member.voiceChannel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('I\'m sorry but you need to be in a voice channel to play music!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(msg.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) {
            return msg.channel.send('I cannot connect to your voice channel, make sure I have the proper permissions!');
        }
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
            return msg.channel.send('I cannot speak in this voice channel, make sure I have the proper permissions!');
        }

        if (url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)) {
            const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url);
            const videos = await playlist.getVideos();
            for (const video of Object.values(videos)) {
                const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
                await handleVideo(video2, msg, voiceChannel, true); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
            }
            return msg.channel.send(`✅ Playlist: **${playlist.title}** has been added to the queue!`);
        } else {
            try {
                var video = await youtube.getVideo(url);
            } catch (error) {
                try {
                    var videos = await youtube.searchVideos(searchString, 10);
                    let index = 0;
                    msg.channel.send(`
__**Song selection:**__
${videos.map(video2 => `**${++index} -** ${video2.title}`).join('\n')}
Please provide a value to select one of the search results ranging from 1-10.
                    `);
                    // eslint-disable-next-line max-depth
                    try {
                        var response = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(msg2 => msg2.content > 0 && msg2.content < 11, {
                            maxMatches: 1,
                            time: 10000,
                            errors: ['time']
                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return msg.channel.send('No or invalid value entered, cancelling video selection.');
                    }
                    const videoIndex = parseInt(response.first().content);
                    var video = await youtube.getVideoByID(videos[videoIndex - 1].id);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return msg.channel.send(' I could not obtain any search results.');
                }
            }
            return handleVideo(video, msg, voiceChannel);
        }
    } else if (command === 'skip') {
        if (!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('You are not in a voice channel!');
        if (!serverQueue) return msg.channel.send('There is nothing playing that I could skip for you.');
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end('Skip command has been used!');
        return undefined;
    } else if (command === 'stop') {
        if (!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('You are not in a voice channel!');
        if (!serverQueue) return msg.channel.send('There is nothing playing that I could stop for you.');
        serverQueue.songs = [];
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end('Stop command has been used!');
        return undefined;
    } else if (command === 'volume') {
        if (!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('You are not in a voice channel!');
        if (!serverQueue) return msg.channel.send('There is nothing playing.');
        if (!args[1]) return msg.channel.send(`The current volume is: **${serverQueue.volume}**`);
        serverQueue.volume = args[1];
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(args[1] / 5);
        return msg.channel.send(`I set the volume to: **${args[1]}**`);
    } else if (command === 'np') {
        if (!serverQueue) return msg.channel.send('There is nothing playing.');
        return msg.channel.send(` Now playing: **${serverQueue.songs[0].title}**`);
    } else if (command === 'queue') {
        if (!serverQueue) return msg.channel.send('There is nothing playing.');
        return msg.channel.send(`
__**Song queue:**__
${serverQueue.songs.map(song => `**-** ${song.title}`).join('\n')}
**Now playing:** ${serverQueue.songs[0].title}
        `);
    } else if (command === 'pause') {
        if (serverQueue && serverQueue.playing) {
            serverQueue.playing = false;
            serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.pause();
            return msg.channel.send('⏸ Paused the music for you!');
        }
        return msg.channel.send('There is nothing playing.');
    } else if (command === 'resume') {
        if (serverQueue && !serverQueue.playing) {
            serverQueue.playing = true;
            serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.resume();
            return msg.channel.send('▶ Resumed the music for you!');
        }
        return msg.channel.send('There is nothing playing.');
    }

    return undefined;
});

async function handleVideo(video, msg, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(msg.guild.id);
    console.log(video);
    const song = {
        id: video.id,
        title: Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title),
        url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`
    };
    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueConstruct = {
            textChannel: msg.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 5,
            playing: true
        };
        queue.set(msg.guild.id, queueConstruct);

        queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

        try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            queueConstruct.connection = connection;
            play(msg.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
            queue.delete(msg.guild.id);
            return msg.channel.send(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
        }
    } else {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        console.log(serverQueue.songs);
        if (playlist) return undefined;
        else return msg.channel.send(`✅ **${song.title}** has been added to the queue!`);
    }
    return undefined;
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    console.log(serverQueue.songs);

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url))
        .on('end', reason => {
            if (reason === 'Stream is not generating quickly enough.') console.log('Song ended.');
            else console.log(reason);
            serverQueue.songs.shift();
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on('error', error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);

    serverQueue.textChannel.send(` Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
}

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Depois de hospedar o bot apresentou o seguinte erro no chat:

> I could not join the voice channel: Error: FFMPEG not found

Erro que aparece no servidor

2018-10-27T22:25:17.011815+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at RESTMethods.login (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RESTMethods.js:33:12)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.011817+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.login (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:279:30)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.011818+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object. (/app/roxy.js:195:8)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.011820+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.011821+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.011823+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.011824+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.011826+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.012621+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
2018-10-27T22:25:17.012786+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: É importante dar mais informações, tipo: OS do servidor,  Você fez a instalação das dependências ? *ffmpeg* é uma dependência e precisa ser instalada. Caso esteja utilizando *Ubuntu* e derivados, execute o comando: `sudo apt install ffmpeg`

Comment: Sim,fiz a instalação

Comment: Então adicione isso: `export PATH=$PATH:<caminho do diretório onde esta instalado ffmpeg>` no arquivo: **~/.bashrc** e veja se funciona.

Comment: Deu certo,obrigado!!.Já estava quebrando a cabeça